# Libkmod Error after installing NVIDIA graphics driver

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I tried to install the NVIDIA graphics driver and after restarting on boot I get a blackscreen with the error:

libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod-configuration.c:635 kmod_config_parse: /etc/mod probe. D/alsa-Base.conf line 44: ignoring bad line starting with 'snd-hda-intel'
/dev/sda6: clean, 739313/3597440 files, 9633353/14415460 blocks
[     7.4487] USB 1-6: device descriptor read/64, error -110

I've read on forums that it is to do with not having enough power in the USB but I've tried plugging my laptop in and it doesn't seem to make a difference

Edit: Apparently this is not the cause of the issue.

I have a Nvidia Geforce 840M graphics card and intel i7 processor. I tried to install the graphics driver using this driver: http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/121199/en-uk and followed the instructions by running:

```
sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.59.run
```

Comment: Ignore the warning. It was there before, you just didn't see it. You see it now because you have no desktop loading. How did you tried to install the drivers? Please [edit] and describe it along with hardware specs.

Comment: @MichaelBay I've added the hardware specs

Comment: The driver version is correct, the method isn't (and can have such unintended consequences). Now you have to uninstall everything  (probably by running the file again with the `--uninstall` argument). Reboot. Open Additional Drivers, select and apply. Reboot again.

Comment: @MichaelBay brilliant thank you! this meant i could reinstall and now it works!